# Reading a file in Python and adding up values based on a variable name

Tags: python, list, file, variables

I have a program that is supposed to read from a file and add up the total sales made from three departments in a hardware store. I think I have most of the code written correctly, except when I print the output of the total sales, the code doesn't seem to add all of the sales for each individual department... it only prints out one value.

Here is my code:

```
def main():
    #open the inventory file
    inventory = open('inventory.txt', 'r')

    #set sale values to zero
    plumbingSales = 0
    LightingSales = 0
    gardenSales = 0

    #for each line in the file
    for line in inventory:
        #strip the \n from the end of each line and split each line into a list
        line = line.rstrip("\n")
        dataList = line.split(",")

        
        #if the department is Plumbing
        if dataList[0] == "Plumbing":
            plumbingSales = 0 + float(dataList[2])
        #if the department is Lighting
        elif dataList[0] == "Lighting":
            lightingSales = 0 + float(dataList[2])
        #if the department is Garden
        elif dataList[0] == "Garden":
            gardenSales = 0 + float(dataList[2])

    #print the sales by department
    print("Sales by Department:")
    print(" ")
    print("Plumbing: $",plumbingSales)
    print("Lighting: $",lightingSales)
    print("Garden: $",gardenSales)
    #add up the sales from all three departments together to get the total sale and then print the total sale
    totalSale = plumbingSales + lightingSales + gardenSales
    print("Total Sales: $",totalSale)
```

I'm positive the problem has something to do with how I ask the program to strip and split the lines. So how would I edit the code so that the program adds up all values from each department as it should?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
plumbingSales = 0 + float(dataList[2])
```

You need to be using a `+=`

```
plumbingSales += float(dataList[2])
```

To add the price to the current running total instead of starting all over.

Comment: Wow... I am an idiot. lol Thanks for the help. I need to really be better about looking closer at my code.

Comment: No problem. It's easy to miss something and get fixated on thinking the problem is elsewhere. Adding in print statements to see what is going on at each step of the process can help or learning how to use a debugger that lets you step through your code.